# Matrix visual result values not pulling for the data

Tags: powerbi

I have three tables.
Table 1  CheckNo  No of Covers

Table 2 Data Tabe with Check Id, Location Id, date Revenue
Table 3 Liaction ID and Location name

Table 1 is linked to Table 2 One to Many relationships on Checkl No
Table 3 is liked to Table 2 one to many relationships on Location ID

Trying to get a matrix visual with Location Name, Month, No of Covers and Sum of Revenue for each location.
Tried the matrix  with Location in Row , Month in Column and Sum of Revenue and Covers in Values
The revenue is coming clean but on covers i am getting the total covers from Table 1 for each location for each month.
I am a beginner, Any heal will be greatly appreciated.
Hem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe part of the problem is that you never told us what actual thing you're modeling. Is this a restaurant? Is a cover a guest/customer? So guests per table? I think Tables 1 and 2 can be merged, so you have Number of Covers in the merged table 2, and table 1 you don't show. Then you have that "Covers" table as a dimension and then the Sales table. Then you can sum revenue, and sum covers.

It might be easier to understand your tables if you showed them as TableName(Attribute1, Attribute2,...)